# How to select checkbox of dynamic HTML table who’s XPath is not fixed and it has label?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to select the checkbox of dynamic HTML table whose XPath is not fixed and it has a label?

Comment: Please share the HTML code. Thanks

Comment: Also, code trials.

Comment: also add error stack trace , if there is any .

Comment: It's interview question asked by one of the interviewers. Just want to know different ways. You can take any example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Xpath :

```
//tag value[contains(@label(),'Label Value')]
```

Comment: //tag value[contains(.,'Label Value')] worked for me

Comment: Found solution what I exactly wanted http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2015/01/selecting-checkbox-from-table-based-on.html